# link media wizard in adobe premiere cannot be found?

Tags: video, video-editing, adobe-premiere

When you open an old Adobe Premier project and some of the videos have moved around on your hard drive you will get a dialog box open and for each file you will get a popup asking you find the file that has since moved.

Take this folder struture:

```
Jamie 
     ¬ Jamie.avi
     ¬ Jamie2.avi
     ¬ Jamie3.avi
     ¬ Jamie4.avi
```

The popup will ask for `Jamie.avi` and i will go and find it, it will then see `Jamie,2,3,4` and auto link these files.

I to save time clicked `offline all` now this popup will no longer open up, more over i now have to manually link each file.

How can i get this dialoge up again?

I thought about editing the `.project` file in note++ but can't find a link to relate to this thing I am after.

Answer (score 0):

As i have spent 3 days trying to sort this out, but some how, after asking this question i have found the answer I think its only right i answer my own question... bad times

The answer:

> If you selected more than one offline clip, the Link Media To dialog
>   box appears in turn for each clip you selected. The title bar of the
>   dialog box gives the filename for each offline clip. Relink the
>   correct source file to each offline clip. If all of the offline clips
>   selected point to media in the same folder, the Link MediaTo dialog
>   asks for the first file, then links the selected offline clips to all
>   the files in the same folder as the file selected.

Taken from: [Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/premierepro/cs/using/WSd79b3ca3b623cac9-5dacca1512743f7a833-8000.html)